# how to get request size in mozilla addon?

Tags: firefox-addon

I have written an add-on for Firefox. I need to get the request size in an `http-on-modify-request` observer:

```
var httpChannel = aSubject.QueryInterface(this.C_interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);
if (aTopic == "http-on-modify-request") {
  // ??? //
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Request size or response size?

Answer (score 0):

To get the length of the POST data you get the `Content-Length` header:

```js
var contentLength = parseInt(httpChannel.getRequestHeader("Content-Length"), 10) || 0;
```

If you also need to calculate the size of the headers being sent you will have to go through them:

```js
var headerLength = 0;
httpChannel.visitRequestHeaders(function(header, value)
{
  headerLength += header.length + ": ".length + value.length + "\r\n".length;
});
```